# "Life has meaning" vs. "life has a meaning"

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

Could you tell me what kind of meaning the use of *a* adds to the following sentence?

> Life has meaning; it's just we can't it figure it out yet.
>
> Life has **a** meaning; it's just we can't it figure it out yet.

I'm sure both sentences are correct as I have seen both *life has meaning* and *life has a meaning* used. I can't figure out the logic behing using *a* before *meaning*.

Comment: to me "Life has meaning" is put more *generally*, while "Life has a meaning" implies the author has *a more particular meaning* in mind and might go on explaining what it is...